# A few questions about working with PHP 5.4

Tags: apache-2.2, php, web-server, php5

I installed PHP 5.4 on Debian from source and I run php scripts on the PHP Built-in web server with new php features without any error but php scripts do not run with apache2 with new php features.

I did not understand the relationship between php and apache2 completely.  So I have a few questions:

1. I can run php scripts with the built-in php server, so is the built-in web server enough to serve php script without any web server such as apache or nginx ? (If you say no, please explain why. )
2. How can I use PHP 5.4 with apache2 ?
3. Why does apache2 not interpret new PHP features even though I installed PHP 5.4 ?
4. Must I compile apache2 again?  If so, why ?
5. What is the relationship betwen apache2, mod_php module and php ?

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/migration54

Comment: *(reference)* [The internal web server is designed for developmental purposes only, and should not be used in production.](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)

Comment: remaining questions belong on ServerFault IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can run php script with built-in php server, so Does built-in web server enough to serve php script without any web server such as apache or nginx ? (If you say no, why? )

- Yes, but ONLY for development. The built in server is very primitive and not meant for production in any shape or form.

How can I use php 5.4 with apache2?

- Install via your distro package manager (if available in a repo) - or compile it; I'd highly suggest you install the Apache devel headers for your mpm. Look into the configure option '--with-apxs2' in the documentation which takes an extra step out of configuration for apache.

Why apache2 does not interpret new PHP features although that I installed PHP 5.4 ?

- If you restarted Apache and it's still running say, 5.3 - then You didn't install or configure it correctly when compiled.

Do I must compile apache2 again , why ?

- Not enough information to help you out on this

How does process relation among apache2,mod_php module and php ?

- Without being too winded: Apache configuration loads the php module (a mere 'key' mapped to the module) which is a .so file. Then it associates files of the PHP filetype to be processed with that SAPI.